# JQuery $(this) and attributes

Tags: jquery

A while back I set up the following to have a very simple image swap using jQuery. Now that the site needs to expand, however, I cannot figure out the actual value of the $(this) selector. I thought it would be $('.gallery li img') but that doesn't seem to be the case. It's been a while since I've looked at this code, and I'm entirely lost.

```
$('.gallery li img').hover(function() {
    var $gallery = $('.gallery li img').parents('.gallery');
    var cur_img = $(this).attr('src').replace('thumb/', '');
    $('.main-img', $gallery).attr('src', cur_img);
});​
```

I don't need a better means to set up a gallery, what I have works fine (although comments are appreciated as always) I just need to figure out the value of $(this) in the given circumstance.

Comment: just console.log($(this)); ? so you can see whats in it?

Comment: can you give a link to the website or a JsFiddle link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't the (this) in jQuery just a self-referential? Meaning, basically, "whatever is currently selected or focussed on?" (Sorry - don't know how to comment, or I'd do that instead.)

Looking at your code, it looks like it's just replacing the current image's source with the prefixed path "thumb/".

Comment: `Sorry - don't know how to comment, or I'd do that instead.`...how did you manage to post your other 21 comments (currently at this time)?

Comment: In other questions and answers, I'd see the "comment" link. When I went to answer this question, there was no link to simply post a comment, even though I'd seen others do exactly that. There were only link options to share | edit | flag. Hence my confusion... (but there was a link to post a comment under this answer.)

Comment: Correct, it should be self-referential, but when exchanged for .gallery li img, which I thought WAS the selector, it ceases to function. Also, not sure what to say about the comments, I'll check and see if I have something disabled somewhere, though I shouldn't.

Comment: Someone up in the comments above noted that this piece of the code is missing the close-bracket and the close-brace. (I'm going to just guess that this isn't the whole code, though?) .gallery li img would be the selector for a CSS stylesheet - one with some very specific rules - but if you wanted to target just things tagged with the class "gallery", use ".gallery" alone. Not the syntax you have, which is class, element, element.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Commenting requires 50+Rep.. I'm guessing the other comments are either on answers/questions Leigh made http://stackoverflow.com/privileges

Comment: @Leigh: Ah, I see. Fair enough, I didn't know/remember that. +1 on comment and answer.

Answer (score 3):

**$(this)** is the current context you are talking about.

So **img** i.e, The current image on which it is hovered..

Try console.log( $(this)) to double check it

Answer (score 1):

`$(this)` in this code refers to the img tag that is being hovered over.

Comment: Never mind, it worked fine with ".gallery li img" to select the same. Strange, considering i dont have any containing quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a little side note, $(this) is indeed the currently referenced element, but it's a jQuery wrapper of that element, a wrapper that has access to all jQuery's methods.
You also have 'this', that refers to the actual DOM element.

Example:
When selecting an image $('img');

$(this) is $('img')

this is `<img src="example/" alt="example">`

You need $(this) to use it along with jQuery's methods and 'this' (disregard the single quotes) to fetch the html element AS IS.

I hope that helps. Just know, in JS/jQuery, it is *crucial* to understand this well, otherwise, it would be pretty impossible to dig more into the JS world.

Answer (score 0):

You could add `console.log('this', $(this));`, then check your console to learn more about the value :)

Comment: If the code you pasted is the entire snippet, you're missing a `)};` at the end.